# Can't find sqlite version 3.9 or greater for djano install

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I tried installing Django on my AWS linux AMI machine.  Right off the bat, I got errors that the current version of Django required sqlite version 3.9 or greater.  So I went about trying to install a version of sqlite that matched the requirements, but had no luck.  So, to get around the issue, I downgraded the Django version to 2.15 which was compatible with the version of sqlite and everything worked just peachy.

Then I wanted to add bootstrap to the project, so I installed with the following command:
pip install django-bootstrap3

That package required a later version of Django, so it uninstalled 2.15 and installed Django 3.2.18.  When I try to run the server, I get the that incompatiblity message with the Django version and sqlite.  (By the way, the exact version of bootstrap was 3-23.1)

I am able to install sqlite via pip: pip install db-sqlite3
But that gives me something earlier than 3.9 which is needed.

So, I could either find an earlier version of bootstrap that works with Django 2.15, or find a later version of sqlite.  Obviously the best fix would be to get a more current version of sqlite.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I've ran into this pre-req disaster before, I just end up compiling my own Python with a more up-to-date Sqlite3- It's not has hard as you'd think!
What OS & Package Manager do you you (apt?- dnf?) - I literally have a script to do it, there's just a couple pre-reqs that have different names depending on what package manager you have.

Comment: This is an Amazon Linux server.  
I use yum for package updates.  
Here's the output of cat /etc/os-release:
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

Answer (score 0):

Here's my script, I recommend just manually running the commands in case there's an issue with one of the pre-reqs.
I've ran it in Centos7, Centos8s and Rocky9, so it should work on your specific one.. and your system should have dnf installed, it's a newer rewrite of yum

#### Couple things to know beforehand:

If your system came with a python3 version already it has to be an alt install `make altinstall`
else it could break everything. Centos8s + Rocky9 comes with a Python3, so the below commands are with an altinstall

The main thing you are looking for is: after the `make` command for Python, look for the uninstalled modules.
I found if you had a lot of them stuff would start breaking. This is my output after running the script below:

```bash
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_tkinter
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

If re-running the `make` process to fix any missing modules, run `make distclean` before the `./configure`

You could also try updating it to fetch python 3.11 instead, but no guarantees it would work..

#### install_python.sh

```bash
# Login as root
sudo su

# general
yum -y update
yum install -y curl gcc make

# Pre-Reqs {{{

yum install -y libffi-devel bzip2-devel readline-devel gdbm-devel libuuid-devel libpq-devel openssl-devel

# enable powertools for libnsl2-devel -> python nis module
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
yum install -y libnsl2-devel

yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'

# sqlite install {{{

cd /tmp
curl -LO https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-autoconf-3410000.tar.gz
tar zxvf sqlite-autoconf-*.tar.gz
rm -rf sqlite-autoconf-*.tar.gz
cd sqlite*/
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
make install

# }}}

# libffi {{{

cd /tmp/
curl -LO https://github.com/libffi/libffi/releases/download/v3.4.4/libffi-3.4.4.tar.gz
tar xzvf libffi-*.tar.gz
rm -rf libffi-*.tar.gz
cd libffi-*
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --disable-docs
make
make install

# }}}

# }}}

# Install {{{

cd /tmp
curl -LO https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.5/Python-3.10.5.tgz
tar xvf Python-*.tgz
rm -rf Python-*.tgz
cd Python-*/
mkdir build
cd build

# only required if already ran make
# make distclean

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64"
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/lib

../configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
make
make altinstall

# Use: `make install` if system doesn't already has a system python3

# alt install,
# Link to Bin so root can use it
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 /usr/bin

# }}}

# vim:fen:fdm=marker:fmr={{{,}}}:fdl=0:fdc=1:ts=2:sw=2:sts=2
```

#### fin

```bash
[vagrant@centos8 ~]$ sqlite3 --version
3.41.0 2023-02-21 18:09:37 05941c2a04037fc3ed2ffae11f5d2260706f89431f463518740f72ada350866d
[vagrant@centos8 ~]$ python3.10
Python 3.10.5 (main, Apr 14 2023, 19:18:44) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.41.0'
```

Should be set for a while

Comment: I do not have DNF installed on my machine, so this script isn't going to work for me.  Is there another way we can get this installed?

Comment: What?! I'm surprised, all my Centos boxes (even 7) had `dnf`, sorry for leading you astray!

I updated my script; `dnf` & `yum` both point to the same repos, so I just did `ctrl+f -> replace dnf /-> yum` & tested it on Centos8. I presume as time goes on you'll see more `dnf`, so just know you replace it with `yum` and it will most likely work.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  I'm not a real linux sys admin, so I went a different direction on this.  I installed the latest version of sqlite3 using this command:

cd ~ && wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3320100 && ./configure && make && make install

I had to download a gcc compiler, add swap space, and update my environment env variable so Django used the proper version of sqlite3.  But I eventually got it all working.

Comment: @Tony yeah it’s usually a disaster. Glad you got it working!